# Raspberry pi power issuses

Tags: usb-power, power-management

i just want to supply power for other devices which uses 5 v dc from the raspberry pi by cutting and soldering the wires and also i want to connect all the USB ports with mouse keyboard WI-FI dongle and also i would like to connect my camera module to raspberry pi.

here my doubt is the is too much load on raspberry pi will that effect my pi

Comment: Cutting cables is the **last resort**! Why?? What are you **actually** trying to achieve?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good idea, to connect a powered USB hub to the Pi and connect the peripherals to that, so their power is not taken from the Pi, but from the hub?

Comment: @Milliways not necessarily

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use an USB hub for something like that.
This will not affect your raspberry pi but a lot of power shall be consumed. So do not forget to use a power supply with 5V 3A of minimum power supply. 
You do not need to solder anything. Pi is a very very delicate electronics board. Be careful before doing soldering.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, too much power consumption may affect rpi performance, and could even may damage the SD card is the rpi is shutting down while writing on it, or worst, damage internal fuse.

2 way to estimate :

1 ) Theoric way : count how much current you will take, and compare to what the rpi can provide. (1.2A on USB, from 16 mA from an individual 3.3V GPIO or more than 50 mA from the GPIO as a whole, but may vary with your rpi version)

2 ) Empiric way : Try to add more and more devices, until you see your rasberry producing smoke and fire.

I strongly recommend the first approach, as it's less risky for your hardware :)

Comment: Unfortunately this perpetuates some of the urban myths! See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations) for detail. The Lightning icon indicates the **voltage** is too low and has almost **NOTHING** to do with current; similarly the Temperature icon is unrelated to current usage of peripherals.

Comment: If you make edits to your answer, please don't leave the incorrect stuff there with a strikethrough. Answers should be *squeaky clean*, without any cruft.

Answer (score 0):

If your setup will allow, please use a powered usb hub. The Pi will push the wifi dongle and k+m easy. I've never hooked up a camera but I would image that the pi is getting close to it's max power draw with all of that plugged in. It would be helpful to just add the powered usb hub so that the Pi is not in danger of losing power when operating. Like mentioned before.. cutting wires and soldering should be last resort!

Comment: There's already an answer written earlier that suggest to use a powered hub.